# Online Privacy from the Facebook ticker while playing games

Tags: facebook, privacy

How can I get Facebook to stop broadcasting when I am online and what I am doing, scrolling on the upper right-hand side of the Facebook page (the ticker)?

Everyone *does not* need to know if I am playing a game.

Answer (score 1):

When authenticating the application to your Facebook account, you should select the option saying that whatever the application posts should be visible to only you and none of your friends.

This is shown in the screenshot below:

[image]